# Execute time-consuming jobs on Azure

Tags: azure

I have used Azure Schedulers before for quick jobs before. It targets a URL which is ASPX page or WebApi and it did the job.

Now I have a job that takes up to 15-20 minutes. Of course, I am getting timeout error after 30 seconds.

I'm trying to avoid creating a Windows Service or some console application that would run on Azure VM, rather have a non-UI application that runs in the background.

Do you have any suggestion what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [Azure WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) for this. WebJobs support simple scheduling via a **cron expression** ([details here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs)). Basically you upload a simple script file or exe that performs the work you want done, upload it to your WebApp along with a cron schedule expression, and Azure WebJobs will make sure it runs on schedule.

For your scenario, you'll want to create a "**Continuous**" WebJob and ensure you've enabled "**Always On**" which ensures the background job continues running (i.e. it isn't request triggered).

Answer (score 0):

WebJobs sure is a good solutions, but it will share resources with its attached Web App.

You could consider using an Azure Cloud Service. I do that myself for longer running tasks, that are more CPU intensive.

[Read more](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

For long running WebJobs, you have to tinker with the [Timeout value](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs) (by default 2 minutes) or make sure your Webjob makes some Console.Writes.

To achieve that, go to the Web App Settings > Application Settings and add the following configurations:

WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT - Time in seconds after which we'll abort a running triggered job's process if it's in idle, has no cpu time or output.

SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT - Time in milisecods. By default, when your build process launches some command, it's allowed to run for up to 60 seconds without producing any output. If that is not long enough, you can make it longer, e.g. to make it 10 minutes: